# Navigation position fixed - impossible to align to the right

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm being unable to align the navigation to the right side while it's positioned fixed. 
I read previous threads and I implemented what was suggested but despite of that I'm not able to make it stay within the main container and to be aligned to the right.
It either doesn't move at all (with float: right) or goes out of the container.

```
<div class="container">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-positioning">
      <div class="menu-primary-navigation-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div>

.container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header .main-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: auto;
}
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

The problem occurs within this site: www.oktawiakata.com 
login: login 
password: superstrongpassword

Thanks a lot in advance for your hints!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not able to make it stay within the main container and to be aligned to the right.

With `position:fixed` the position of your element will be relative to the browser window, so it's not exactly correct to say that it will stay within the main container in CSS terms.

If you want it to stay within the main container, you should use `position: absolute`

```
#main-container{
    position: relative;
}
#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Use this code for a navigation bar like the example provided on your comment:

HTML

```
<div id="navigation-bar">
    <div class="navigation-content">
        <ul class="navigation-menu">
            <!-- Your <li> elements here -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation-bar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
#navigation-bar .navigation-content{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: right
}
#navigation-bar .navigation-content ul{
    // Your list styles ...
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your help. I want to make it stay within my class .container, when it comes to the width, but at the same time always on the top. I am able to stick it to the top and it stays on the left WITHIN the container of my class .container . I'm not able move it to the right, like here: www.vagabondyogis.com

Comment: @Aiwatko Take a look at the updated answer. It's not a complete code, but should be enough to understand how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

When your element is positioned as a fixed element, then you need to change right value to 0px;

```
#someContainerCSS{
    position: fixed;
    right   : 0px;
}
```

That should do the work.

Comment: P.S. I did not open the site.